# javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to do a regex where if the value is less than 10 then, it should alert some error message. how could I do it using regex. i am  learning regex and so have little knowledge on this. Please help?

Comment: Can't you just do `if(value < 10)` ?

Comment: This doesnt really seem like an applicable use of a regular expression... regex is for pattern matching, not for value checking.

Comment: There is no need to use regex for a numeric comparison operation such as this. See Vache's solution.

Answer (score 2):

For checking if a value (presumably you mean number) is less than ten I don't see that regex is appropriate.

```
if (myValue < 10) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Regular expressions are used for string pattern operations mainly, not numeric operations like this.

Answer (score 2):

I would urge you to use normal JavaScript math for this. Regexes are for processing strings, not numbers. All you really need is this:

```
if (val < 10 ) {
    alert(message);
}
```

However, if you **must** use a regex for this, this should work:

```
/^(\+?0*|-\d*)\d(\.\d+)?$/
```

It accepts any positive number from 0-9, or any negative number, ignoring leading zeroes and any decimal places.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following regex

```
\b[0-9]{1}\b|-\b[0-9]+\b
```

the first part before the OR | is used to find digits from 0 to 9 in a word boundary, the second part after the OR | is used to capture -ve numbers.

You need to mark the regex with multiline and global flag too.

Comment: This will check if the value is greater than 10, i.e. if it is greater than 10 then it will alert error msg. What I need is that to alert the error msg if the user has entered a value less than 10

Comment: this regex will mark all the numbers that are less than 10, the left part of the regex takes care of numbers from 0 to 9 and the left part of the regex takes care of -ve numbers. The full regex is: /\b[0-9]{1}\b|-\b[0-9]+\b/gm

Comment: `{1}` is always redundant in a regex. It's implied.

Comment: But this seems to be accepting values only from 0 to 9. Not 11 and greater than 11??

Comment: @Justin Morgan, you are right, I just wanted it to be clear as he said that he is a beginner

Comment: You said: "What I need is that to alert the error msg if the user has entered a value less than 10"
You can use this regex to check if he entered anything less than 10 or not, if he entered anything less than 10, this regex will match them and you can alert your error message, if no matches then user didn't enter any value less than 10 which is okay

Comment: `-\b[0-9]+` is also the same as `-[0-9]+` or `-\d+`. There's always a `\b` between `-` and `[0-9]`.

Comment: I am using validation Engine.js plugin. So here is the code which I have put as per your suggestion "min": {
                    "regex": /\b[0-9]{1}\b|-\b[0-9]+\b/,
                    "alertText": "* Minimum value is 10"
                },  But this would alert if the user has entered value greater than 10